# OpenCV cascade classifier from Python

Tags: python, c++, opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a computer vision/machine learning problem in python and have so far not needed opencv. However, I now need to use a fast cascade classifier to detect objects in a set of images. I came across the [Haar based classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) written in C++. The testing phase can be called from Python, but I cannot find a way to train the classifier to recognize other objects from Python (I was only able to find [this](http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html), which uses C++).

1. Is the training functionality of the Haar cascade only available through C++ or can it be used with Python?
2. If only C++, any pointers on what I need to install to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: Look here: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html

Comment: Thanks! That link however only goes over the testing phase of the algorithm, not the training phase. It seems like I may need to understand how to use the C++ binaries if I want to do training.

Comment: You'd have to implement your own cascades, which I believe is only a C++ thing.  You can use any of the pre-built cascades that OpenCV provides directly in Python, but in terms of making your own cascades, I don't think it's possible outside of C++.

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/d88/tutorial_traincascade.html